# Box muller random number between 0 and 1 in c++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to create a Gaussian random number generator that will produce values between 0 and 1. I have been trying to use the below function with mean value 0 and standard deviation of 1, but when I generate random numbers via this function using a loop, I end up with a majority of my values being generated outside of my range of [0,1]. How would I go about adjusting what I am doing to bring those values inside that range?

```
float Network::box_muller(float m, float s) {                     
float x1, x2, w, y1;
static float y2;
static int use_last = 0;

if (use_last) {
    y1 = y2;
    use_last = 0;
}
else {
    do {
        x1 = 2.0 * ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) - 1.0;
        x2 = 2.0 * ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) - 1.0;
        w = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
    } while (w >= 1.0);

    w = sqrt((-2.0 * log(w)) / w);
    y1 = x1 * w;
    y2 = x2 * w;
    use_last = 1;
}

return(m + y1 * s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For production code:**

If you have access to C++11 features then you should be using `std::normal_distribution` 
 (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) or one of its variants, rather than implementing the functionality yourself. This should give you a robust (does not use `rand()`), thread safe (yours is not), well tested implementation.

**For learning purposes**

Wikipedia has an example implementation of this algorithm in C++. Specifically I can see two issues with your code.

1. You do not correctly handle the case of `w==0`. I.e. `log(0)` and division by zero are undefined.
2. Your update function for `y1` and `y2` is incorrect. The correct algorithm (in pseudo-code): `y1 = sqrt(-2 * log(u1)) * cos(2*PI*u2)` and `y2 = sqrt(-2 * log(u1)) * sin(2*PI*u2)` where clearly `u1` must be in the range (0, 1), while u2 is unconstrained.

Also on a minor syntactic point. Your `use_last` variable should be a `bool`, rather than an `int` in C++.

Comment: It looks like the [Marsaglia method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) is being used.

Comment: You're quite right. The question mentions (mentioned) the Box Muller method, so I assumed that, that was what he wanted to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost fine (almost, because sometimes it’ll crash with division by zero).

If you need random numbers that are limited to some range, you probably don’t want to use Gaussian distribution. Gaussian values are unlimited. The probability falls pretty quickly around the mean value, but it never reaches the exact zero. For example, the probability of the value to fall outside [m-3*s; m+3*s] interval is only 0.27%, but it’s not 0.